# Multi Currency application data structure

Tags: mongodb, nuxt.js

i am working on my travel activity application, it will be available in multi currency, i am confused about data structure for multi currency.
I am using Nuxtjs, Vuejs, Express and Mongodb.

what should be the best way.

1. do i need to store value of every product in each currency in documents and request data using currency
2. or, just store the value of every product in a base currency like US Dollar and create another collection with conversion rate of each currency

what should be the ideal way?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question that is more of a product-based decision making here. There is no strict universal convention IMO.

Comment: thanks for answer kissu ! but according to you, what can you suggest? as i said, travel products like klook, getyourguide sells.

Comment: You could store a reference value for the product and pass it through a middleware to determine the exact amount. The structure of it is totally up to you. Giving a price to something internationally is not trivial IMO.